# adding a WHERE clause to this statement

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I am looking to add a where clause to the following:

```
<?php foreach($this->assignments as $assignmentIndex => $assignmentArray): ?>
```

I want basically to only pull data from the database where assignmentType=pdf

any help would be great!

thanks

Comment: Where is the query? You have posted a for loop!

Comment: this is not mysql but some PHP-based library. You have to state that labrary to get proper answer.

Comment: But in the code example above; the information is already pulled out of the database, right? So if you want to filter the result; you should do that on the query. Otherwise you should use an if statement inside the foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($this->assignments as $assignmentIndex => $assignmentArray): ?>
    <?php if(assignmentType == 'pdf') :?>
    ....
    ....
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php end foreach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can't change the sql line in the foreachloop
however if the assignmentArray containts assignmenType 
you could ignore the other types like this:

```
if($assignmentArray['assignmentType'] != 'pdf'){
    continue; 
}
```

or somewhat nicer would be:

```
if($assignmentArray['assignmentType'] == 'pdf'){
        // do your fancy stuff here
    }
```